# String conversion and encoding

Tags: python, encoding, python-cryptography

I have a string in the database which is an encoded string. How can I change it to the byte datatype such that it does not give error using python.

string in data base = 'b''yAe45XvJkMzMkhP_c6NDKe_OzJyxyJPidssdT4yOFSmT-S02iMXn8_RuC4EsPu9EiPE9KuXLUpR1CIsOnTrfKjmqjYz5rOG8Fplr6NUbFk2sdsdtrPDq_SpV7vg='''

```
Code : 
encMessage1 = df['data_value'][4] #calling string from MYSQL database
encMessage1 = encMessage1.encode()
cont = fernet.decrypt(encMessage1).decode()
```

It is showing error in the string and the output is not displayed properly

Error :
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

Error string after using encode() - b"b'yAe45XvJkMzMkhP_c6NDKe_OzJyxyJPidssdT4yOFSmT-S02iMXn8_RuC4EsPu9EiPE9KuXLUpR1CIsOnTrfKjmqjYz5rOG8Fplr6NUbFk2sdsdtrPDq_SpV7vg='"

How can I resolve this issue? Also, How can call a byte datatype stored in string without any error ?

Comment: So the string stored in the database _literally_ begins with `b"` and ends with `"` ?

Comment: It seems what you have is a string representation of a bytestring.  If that is the case, the process that inserts the value into the database is defective; it should be decoding the bytestring before inserting.

Comment: @pepoluan I have encrypted the string and dumped it into the MYSQL table, and then I am calling it for decryption using the decrypt method. However, I am not able to convert the string into byte format. How should I resolve it ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes. My use case is as follows : I have data in MYSQL table which I want to secure by inserting an encrypted value and replacing the string with these encrypted value for security purpose. How should I approach this ? I believe key has to be static since the data in the MYSQL table will be decrypted using this key. Can you suggest some approach ?

Comment: It's hard to say because the problem lies in how the values are being inserted, and that code is not shown in the question.

Comment: @starlord You haven't answered my question. Does the string currently stored in the database _literally_ starts with `b"` _and_ ends with `"`?

Comment: @pepoluan no the string is like this in database - b'gAAAAABhXvJkMzMkhP_c6NDKe_OzJyxyJPidT4yOFSmT-S02iMXn8_RuC4EsPu9EiPE9KuXLUpR1CIsOnTrfKjmqjYz5rOG8Fplr6NUbFk2trPDq_SpV7vg=' 


However, if I'm applying to_bytes(), I'm getting string like this : - 
'b''yAe45XvJkMzMkhP_c6NDKe_OzJyxyJPidssdT4yOFSmT-S02iMXn8_RuC4EsPu9EiPE9KuXLUpR1CIsOnTrfKjmqjYz5rOG8Fplr6NUbFk2sdsdtrPDq_SpV7vg='''


How can I convert the str datatype input to string?

Comment: Okay, so it **_does_** start with the `b` _bytes repr marker_ literally.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my question in the comments, the data is being stored with the *bytes repr marker*.

The solution is to **chop off** the bytes marker:

```
enc_message1 = enc_message1[2:-1]
```

*Then* use `.encode()`

Comment: The solution is to not store it with the bytes marker in the database in the first place.  Somewhere someone called `str()` on a `bytes` object.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Also, I did try hexidigest() but I'm not able to convert it back to the required format

Comment: @MarkTolonen, sure that is fixing the root cause of the problem. But if the data is already stored in this way, then one can still workaround the issue by doing a simple slicing.